# How to load database data in chosen js dropdown

Tags: php, html, mysql, jquery-chosen

This is my html data:

```
<select class='ssc' id="selectCity" name='bachelorInstituteType' style='width: 200px;'>
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Chosen js and ajax to load data from database  ---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".ssc").chosen();
        function loadlocation() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "loadlocation.php",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#selectCity").append(data);

                }
            });
        };

        loadlocation();
    });
```

loadlocation.php page data :

```
<?php
include "./includes/connection.php";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM city";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$data= "";
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data.= "<option value='{$row['cityName']}'>  {$row['cityName']}  </option>";
        }
    }

echo $data;

?>
```

here (cityName) data is coming form database. The problem is chosen select box is not showing the data but if I make a simple dropdown then it works. Please give me a solution.

Comment: `$("#selectCity")`?? The `select` menu shown has no ID attribute - only a name!

Comment: sorry I forget to put it. But still after that it is not working.

Comment: _"if I make a simple dropdown then it works"_ - I'm not sure I'm following you here? Are you using some library or something on the `#selectCity`-dropdown which you're trying to update? Please clarify that and add all the necessary details to your question (what library you're using or any JS code you have that does something with it).

Comment: Yes sir I am using chosen js library. And sir 'about simple dropdown means' when I don't use any library then the ajax works. But I want to use the library and get the job done. Did you understand sir?

Comment: When you say `" I am using chosen js library"` - do you refer specifically to `jQuery-chosen`? If so ( and presumably that is the case ) then what does ` $(".ssc").chosen();` do precisely? I'd have thought that the callback `loadlocation` would be supplied to that `$(".ssc").chosen();` somehow - as a parameter perhaps or chained like a Promise??